# is there a way to add a dynamic view shortcut on clearcase via a command line?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-automation

I am looking for a way to add a dynamic view shortcut to clearcase, given the view tag and path.
I have looked at cleartool commands but didn't seem to find the right one.

thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Check first if starting the dynamic view is enough for a shortcut to appear: [`cleartool startview myView`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.2/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_startview.htm).

If by "ClearCase", you mean the [ClearCase Explorer](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.2/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.tutorial.doc/topics/a_underst_ccexplorer.htm), then a `cleartool` command might not be needed.
See "[To add dynamic view shortcuts in Rational® ClearCase Explorer (Windows)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.dev.doc/topics/cc_mvfs/to_add_scut_dyn.htm)"

> - in the Shortcut pane, click the Views tab
> - Right-click in the Views tab and click Add View Shortcut.
> - In the Add a New View Shortcut window, from the View Type list, select Dynamic.
> - Select a view from the View Tag list.

As mentioned in "[About adding shortcuts to programs in Rational ClearCase Explorer](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.dev.doc/topics/cc_dev/about_shortcuts_ccexp.htm)"

> These shortcuts let you customize Rational ClearCase Explorer to meet your needs. A Rational ClearCase administrator can make tool and URL shortcuts that are tailored to specific project teams.

In pure command-line, you could create symlink (even in a Windows environment), but you would not need `cleartool` for that.
As shown in "[About dynamic view access model (Windows)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.dev.doc/topics/cc_mvfs/c_about_dynaview_access_model_win.htm)", you can also assign a drive letter to a view, which is like the `net use` command.